# Using jQuery to filter email addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started out on jQuery and want to use it to solve this problem: I have a list of email addresses from different domains currently residing inside divs. Using `.each()`, want to loop through each email addresses and only pick out those that do not have the domain '@gmail.com'. In other words, `somebody@yahoo.com` gets appended to another div, file `somebody@gmail.com` does not. How can I do this?

**jQuery**

*Currently the code simply grabs all emails but does no filtering*

```
$('.email_address').each(function() {
    $(this).html().appendTo('#filtered_email_address');   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
$('.email_address').not(':contains("@gmail.com")').each(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#filtered_email_address');   
});
```

If you specifically want to filter them, try this:

```
$('.email_address').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf('@gmail.com') != 0;
}).each(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#filtered_email_address');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easy with `indexOf` method:

```
$('.email_address').each(function() {
    var email = $(this).text()
    if (email.indexOf('@gmail.com') == -1)
      ('#filtered_email_address').append(email);   
});
```